# How can I get the D3.js axis ticks and positions as an array?

Tags: d3.js

I usually place my axis ticks on the svg using this:

```
d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale(width)).ticks(4)
```

Is it possible to get these tick values and their svg coordinates so I can use a custom axis outside the svg using `d3.svg.axis()` ?

Comment: You should get them if you call `xScale.ticks()`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, `xScale.ticks(4)` should give you the actual tick points as values, and you can pipe those back through your `xScale` to the the X position.  You can also just pull the tick points back from the generated elements after you apply the axis to an actual element:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([20, 280])
    .domain([0, 100])

var axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(scale).orient("bottom").ticks(9);
// grab the "scale" used by the axis, call .ticks()
// passing the value we have for .ticks()
console.log("all the points", axis.scale().ticks(axis.ticks()[0]));
// note, we actually select 11 points not 9, "closest guess"

// paint the axis and then find its ticks
svg.call(axis).selectAll(".tick").each(function(data) {
  var tick = d3.select(this);
  // pull the transform data out of the tick
  var transform = d3.transform(tick.attr("transform")).translate;

  // passed in "data" is the value of the tick, transform[0] holds the X value
  console.log("each tick", data, transform);
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/recig/3/edit)

Comment: What is the v4 equivalent?

Comment: I'm not yet sure myself, I've not had to solve this problem, but if someone does have a v4 equiv, please feel free to edit/amend the answer.

Comment: Addendum inserted for getting tickValues with v4.

Comment: [A D3 v4 answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006369/d3-v4-get-the-value-of-the-each-tick-present-on-an-axis) (tldc; it's `axis.scale().ticks()`, or just `someScaleObject.ticks() if the scale obj is accessible`)

Comment: axis.scale().ticks() in d3 v4 can return the wrong number of ticks. I had set 5 ticks but it was returning 11.

Answer (score 1):

In d3 v4 I ended up just parsing the rendered x values from the tick nodes

```
function parseX(transformText) {
    let m = transformText.match(/translate\(([0-9\.]*)/);
    let x = m[1];
    if (x) {
        return parseFloat(x);
    }
}
```