# D3js Tick Position Minified

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to get the position of the ticks in my y-axis. I am using D3js to create the axes. I [found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722952/how-can-i-get-the-d3-js-axis-ticks-and-positions-as-an-array/22737084#22737084) which is great until I minify my project.

This line isn't minifying nicely:

```
d3.transform(tick.attr("transform")).translate;
```

Any advice on why this wouldn't minify correctly? Or better yet, if you have another solution to get the position of the ticks, that would be great as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to minify? That sounds more like the problem...

Comment: don't find a good reason why it should not minify...

Comment: What does it minify to?

Comment: Was using closure compiler for minification. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not using the d3.transform helper.

Instead I chose to do this manually, essentially using the same concepts:

```js
      var tick = d3.select(this);
      var t = tick.attr('transform');
      var n = t.substring(t.lastIndexOf(',')+1,t.lastIndexOf(')'));
      tickPos.push(Math.round(n));
```