# How can I know what dates are displayed in the axis?

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, time, axis

I've created an xAxis for a date range split to 5 ticks, how can I 'get' the tick values?
e.g: ticks display jan, feb, march, april, may. which d3 function retrieves these value?

```
   var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }))
        .range([0, width]);

    var xAxis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Originally I closed your question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46006369/5768908), but on a second thought it's not an adequate duplicate, because you're changing the number of ticks with `ticks(n)`.

Therefore, the solution is using that same number to get your ticks. In your case:

```
var myTicks = x.ticks(5);
```

Here is a basic demo:

```js
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date("2017"), new Date("2018")])
  .range([20, 480]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5);

var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);

console.log(x.ticks(5))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Have in mind that, given your question's **title**, I'm assuming that you want the actual *date objects*, not the strings in your axis.

Comment: thanks, how can i check the ticks after a transitions? xAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(TICKS_COUNT))

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. I suggest you post a new question, with all relevant details.

Comment: I take it back, I found the answer.